# Running Paraffin when building a wixproj

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, paraffin

I've got a WiX project which pulls in a WiX Fragment with a load of supporting files.

I'm using Paraffin to build the wsx file for the fragment.  At the moment I manually run a one line batch file to run with paraffin with the appropriate arguments whenever I make a change the supporting files folder.

Instead I would like paraffin to run as part of the build process.  I'm guessing I need to add something to  inside the .wixproj file, but I'm not actually sure what.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="paraffin -dir SourceDir -groupname MyGroupId -dirref MyDirId output.wxs"/>

  </Target>
```